# What does ImageSize -> 1 -> 1 mean?

Tags: undocumented, rule

On the page http://www.wolfram.com/language/gallery/blur-faces-in-an-image/ the example code has `ImageSize -> 1 -> 1`. I am unfamiliar with this chaining of rules... What does it mean?  Note I know what `ImageSize` does, it is the TWO arrows that I don't understand.

Comment: syntactically it sets the `ImageSize` option to the rule "1->1".  What that means in terms of `Graphics` I don't know and It doesnt appear to be documented (It definitely does *something* , its not an error and its not the same as `ImageSize->1`  )

Comment: FYI: This syntax is not recognized in version 7.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `FullForm`, you can see that `ImageSize -> 1 -> 1` is the same as `ImageSize -> (1 -> 1)` i.e., the option value itself is a rule. This appears to be an undocumented shorthand for scaling a graphics to the correct image size or to scale up/down by a factor.

Observe the following, using a modified version of the example:

```
img = Import@"http://www.wolfram.com/language/gallery/blur-faces-in-an-image/images/O_1.png"

Clear@scale
scale[a_, b_] := Module[{faces = FindFaces[img]},
    ImageDimensions@Graphics[Disk[Mean[##], First@Differences[##]/2] & /@ faces, 
        PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]}], ImageSize -> a -> b]
]

scale @@@ Tuples[{1, 2}, 2]
(* {{285, 228}, {570, 456}, {143, 114}, {285, 228}} *)
```

`{285, 228}` is the size of `img` and the rest are scaled up/down. You can interpret the rule as `ImageSize -> originalScale -> resizedScale`. Leaving out this option is **not** the same, because then the size of the graphics is `{360, 288}`.

This is very handy when used with functions like `ImageCompose`, `ImageAdd`, `ImageMultiply`, because you can very easily set the mask to be the same size as the original image or scale the same mask for different sizes of the image without having to calculate or recompute the dimensions.