# Converting a list of colors into an image

Tags: graphics, matrix, image, list-manipulation

I want to manipulate colors, and merge the resulting vector and rasterize it into an image, controlling the resolution of the pixel.

E.g. I tried to:

[image]

But what I would like to have is an image of 3 square, blue, red and green, so that:

- I can control the size of the square (e.g. in pixels, say a square 32x32 each)
- (possibly!) I can have controls not to have the black perimeter line of the squares.

I can see there is an example to convert a matrix to graphics :

[image: Image[(]

but cannot figure out how to achieve that with colors - e.g. by converting the color in values and than shape a matrix NxM..

Final thing, it will be exporting:
I'd like to possibly determine the min size of square "pixel" in pixels:

[image]

How to convert a list of colors into arrays or matrixes, and then to an image, using above criteria?

Comment: @m_goldberg - all answers are correct and I see you added a third one and even are editor. I marked as "correct" the first chronologically received.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
colors = RandomColor[{5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Image[colors, ImageSize -> 1 -> 32]
```

[image]

If you a list of list of numbers instead of colors as input, you can use

```
list = colors /. RGBColor -> List;
Image[list, ImageSize -> 1 -> 32]
```

> same picture

Comment: Is the syntax `ImageSize -> 1 -> 32` documented somewhere?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, afaik it is not documented. Earliest reference I could find on this site is [this answer by rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43823/125). See also [this answer by CarlWoll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145446/125)

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of using `Rasterization` can be made to work. You must take window magnification into account to get to proper size in pixels.

```
swatchToRaster[color_?ColorQ, size_ /; size > 0, mag_Real: 1.25] :=
  Rasterize[color , ImageSize -> size/mag]

Row[Prepend[swatchToRaster[#, 32, 1.5] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue}, Spacer[50]]]
```

[image: colors]

I used the ruler tool from the xTools app to prove that the size of rasterized swatches are indeed 32 x 32 pixels.

[image: measured]

Note: when defining `swatchToRaster`, I gave the `mag` argument the default of 1.25 because I normally work with notebooks having magnification set to 125%. You should change this default if you normally use a different window magnification.

Answer (score 2):

Each color is represented by a triplet of values {r,g,b} where each element is drawn from 0 to 1. You can get a matrix of these, turn it into an image with Image, and then resize:

```
Image[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 5, 3}], ImageSize -> 1 -> 32]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting use of `RandomReal[]`. However I did not understood exactly how r,g,b triples are treated by Image[]  - if I try `Image[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 6, 121}]]`, I see `{5,6}` are the matrix size, maybe 121 the number of channels?

Comment: The matrix sent to image should be {rows, col, 3} where 3 is the {r,g,b} value. I'm not sure what to expect if the third entry is larger than 3.